# How to sort the Stack Bars in NVD3 based on Key

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

The graph is stacked vertical chart.
I have below data, the data is grouped based on the Country. As of now, nvd3 is displaying the stacks are built on the bar, ordered by the Key. Is there any way to sort the Stacks of the bar based on the y-axis value.

```
var data = [
            {
                "key" : "India`",
                "values" : [
                    {
                        "x" : "(0-3)",
                        "y" : 0.1
                    },
                    {
                        "x" : "(4-10)",
                        "y" : 0.4
                    },
                    {
                        "x" : "(11-15)",
                        "y" : 0.6
                    },
                    {
                        "x" : "(16-20)",
                        "y" : 0.2
                    },
                    {
                        "x" : "(>21)",
                        "y" : 0.2
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "key" : "Pakistan",
                "values" : [
                    {
                        "x" : "(0-3)",
                        "y" : 0.2
                    },
                    {
                        "x" : "(4-10)",
                        "y" : 0.4
                    },
                    {
                        "x" : "(11-15)",
                        "y" : 0.2
                    },
                    {
                        "x" : "(16-20)",
                        "y" : 0.2
                    },
                    {
                        "x" : "(>21)",
                        "y" : 0.6
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
```

Comment: Can you post a plunkr/jsfiddle?